# How do i use the values from case to do calculations in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'users' with a lot of users in it, my users have 4 different options of signing in: passwd, facebook_login, google_login and aprofiel_login. 
I want to create a query which gets the results:

- total amount of users
- users with only passwd set
- users with only facebook_login set
- users with only google_login set
- users with only aprofiel_login set
- users with more than 1 of the above 4 options set

I came up with the following query which gives me the first 5, but I am unable to get the one which counts the multiples.

my query is like this:

```
select count(*) total,
    sum(case when passwd is not null and (facebook_login is null and google_login is null and aprofiel_login is null) then 1 else 0 end) gad,
    sum(case when facebook_login is not null and (passwd is null and google_login is null and aprofiel_login is null) then 1 else 0 end) facebook,
    sum(case when google_login is not null and (passwd is null and facebook_login is null and aprofiel_login is null) then 1 else 0 end) google,
    sum(case when aprofiel_login is not null and (passwd is null and facebook_login is null and google_login is null) then 1 else 0 end) aprofiel
from `users`
where auth_level = 1
and is_account_active = 1
```

Then I considered, I have my total amount, i have the amount of all the other single ones, if i subtract the total with all the other ones, i have the result for the multiple login user.
But how do i do this in MySQL?

Comment: `total - (gad + facebook + google + aprofiel)`

Comment: @JNevill Thanks! I know how to do this in PHP, but how do I get this into mysql? if i try putting that in the select it does not know the column names

Comment: Looks like Mysql can't use the derived fields in the same SELECT, so you have to stick this all in a subquery and then do the math. Example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick this query into a subquery, and then do your math on the derived columns:

```
SELECT
   t1.*,
   total - (gad + facebook + google + aprofiel) as otherfield
FROM
   (
      select count(*) total,
        sum(case when passwd is not null and (facebook_login is null and google_login is null and aprofiel_login is null) then 1 else 0 end) gad,
        sum(case when facebook_login is not null and (passwd is null and google_login is null and aprofiel_login is null) then 1 else 0 end) facebook,
        sum(case when google_login is not null and (passwd is null and facebook_login is null and aprofiel_login is null) then 1 else 0 end) google,
        sum(case when aprofiel_login is not null and (passwd is null and facebook_login is null and google_login is null) then 1 else 0 end) aprofiel
      from `users`
      where auth_level = 1
        and is_account_active = 1
    ) t1
```